# Is a young black dragon enough of a challenge alone for group of five level-5 characters?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, encounter-design

I have a 5-member party in D&D 5e (ranger, fighter, sorcerer, rogue and bard) who are all level 5. They will soon be meeting with the "big bad", a [young black dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/young-black-dragon), in his lair which contains pools of acid. They would most likely be fully rested before the fight.

I know the CR is 7, but I was wondering whether it would prove to be a satisfying battle, in the sense that they may come close to defeat and might be able to beat the odds.

**Is this fight well-balanced? Would it be challenging?**

If not, should I add some hatchlings or small mobs to adjust the action economy appropriately?

Comment: Have you read the DMG's guide on encounter building?

Comment: Please note whether you should or shouldn't do something is opinion-based/subjective and not something this site is built to handle. Whether the party would be able to handle the encounter is probably something we can answer but we also need to know what level the PCs are. Also, as Erik has asked, have you been through the encounter building steps in the DMG? This seems simple enough to answer by reading those rules. If you have read through it but aren't sure of something specific please include what you're confused about in your question.

Comment: I've seen somewhere that any encounter with only one enemy are usually much easier than it sounds as that said one big bad can be focused down by mere numbers. However, I am hesitant to add in more to this as it might turn deadly and i do not wish to kill anyone (one player died previously already). But both story wise and tension wise, having a young black dragon for them at this point is imperative.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey: The party's level is in the title. I've edited into the body of the question as well.

Answer (score 11):

### This is likely between Medium and Hard difficulty encounter for the party

You can find general guidance on encounter difficulty in the Dungeon Master's Guide (DMG) in the Creating Encounters Section. For level 5 characters, the XP table shows:

> Level ------- Easy --- Medium --- Hard --- Deadly
>
> [...]
>
> 5th ----------    250 ----    500 --------    750 -----   1,100

This means that 5 level five characters would treat a Young Black Dragon (XP =  2,900) as a Medium encounter (5 * 500 = 2,500). While there are some monsters that break this mold and difficulty can be increased depending on the composition of enemies, this is a good rough metric.

#### Consider the level of optimization in your party

If your characters are particularly good at dealing lots of damage or protecting a single character, boss battles like this will be easier than usual and you should increase the difficulty by about 100 XP per level so 500 XP (this is a number I've used in the past and has worked wonders for me).

If you have new players and/or players who are not tactically minded or are unfamiliar with the mechanics, you should decrease the difficulty to the next lowest setting (an Easy encounter will be Medium, a Medium encounter will be Hard, etc.)

#### How hard do you want it to be?

> satisfying battle in the sense that they coming close to defeat and beating the odds.

This sounds like you want it to be somewhere between Hard and Deadly, which a dragon on its own won't accomplish (unless your party fits the "new player"  category I described earlier).

To fix this, you will need your XP approximation to equal 4000-5000. Adding just one Black Dragon Wyrmling pushes the number to the top end of this value at 5,025 due to the Modify Total XP for Multiple Monsters section in the DMG (2 monsters means a 1.5x multiplier).

For a lesser difficulty, but still a suitable challenge, try adding a CR 1 monster like a Goblin Boss or just add a couple of terrain effects to increase the difficulty indirectly.

For a higher difficulty, pushing into the Deadly range, you will need a CR 3 monster like a Bugbear Chief, or add terrain effects or traps to the Dragon and Wyrmling encounter.

Comment: Sounds good, i actually had the idea of adding like 2 dragon eggs which can hatch into wyrmlings if left unattended for 2-3 rounds. The players have seen dragon eggs before and will know it could hatch (i will make the eggs move and shake so they also know). you said that adding one wyrmling would push it to hard-deadly. So with the added delay of hatching and potential 2 wyrmlings if they do not deal with it, is it as much of a challenge as one wyrmling right off the bat?

Comment: @CuriosMaximus Should be good, just keep in mind that if the party can't deal enough damage fast enough, having a dragon and 2 wyrmlings at any given time will likely result in multiple PC deaths even if they have party cohesion and experience just from the sheer amount of damage they can deal in 1 round. So, you might want to just GM-fiat that the second wyrmling can;t come out until the other one is beaten.

Comment: good idea, maybe if the first one gets out and they seem on the losing end the second egg can be a stillborn, but the ranger and fighter both have sharpshooter and if they nuke the first baby right out of the water i'll make the second one all good. thanks mate!

Comment: FWIW, I ran through a few mock combats using a party of a 6th level Druid and Ranger, two fifth level characters (Rogue, Fighter) versus a young green dragon.  It was a winnable encounter for that party, but the dragon can also win (I subbed in an elf for the original dwarf rogue for two tries and the dragon won one of those).

Answer (score 5):

### No, they would likely not break a sweat defeating a Young Black Dragon.

The dragon, at CR 7, is worth 2900 experience points.

Checking the DMG on encounter building (pg 81) we can calculate that a 2900xp encounter for a group of 5 characters at 5th level would be classified as "Hard", but only barely (as anything between 2501xp and 3750xp is Hard). Note that "Hard" is described as:

> **Hard.** A hard encounter could go badly for the
> adventurers. Weaker characters might get taken out
> of the fight, and there's a slim chance that one or more
> characters might die.

Not really a "beating the odds" kind of fight. Especially a party that is fully rested will likely have no problems at all defeating such a creature. Perhaps if they were already worn out from an entire day of adventuring, they might consider this scary. But if they know this is the biggest, baddest thing in the dungeon, they will just drop their powerful abilities on it and kill it easily.

You should probably add in a bunch of other threats to up the scale, to at least the "Deadly" category. The guide can instruct you further on how to do it, I'd suggest reading that section.

Answer (score 1):

A GM who plays the dragon intelligently (as a dragon should be played) will likely be able to defeat a level 5 group. An intelligent enemy should be more challenging than its CR.

First off, a black dragon's lair will be underwater. She will pop up, do her breath weapon (average of 49 damage) such that it hits at least 2 party members, then (in the same turn) dives back underwater. At 5th level, 49 damage is enough to kill a 16-Constitution fighter from full health. And even if characters make their saves, it certainly outpaces damage a healer can do. An intelligent dragon will never stand toe-to-toe and facetank melee damage.

So a level 5 party COULD kill a young black dragon with some exceptional planning and some luck... but if the encounter is anything less than VERY challenging, it's because the DM is slow-pitching to the party.

Comment: Hi Ozy, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] or ask here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) for more information. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score -2):

While not the most ferocious amongst their kin, black dragons deserve no less respect than the rest.
If you are facing a black dragon, it will have to be on their terms or else they won't be fighting your group.

They are quick in joining a combat but just as quick in fleeing.  They will certainly use any dirty tactics and prefer not to face dive into your tank.
These creatures are extremely intelligent and to top that just as wise.

> STR 19 (+4) DEX 14 (+2) CON 17 (+3) INT 12 (+1) WIS 11 (+0) CHA 15 (+2)
> *Acid Breath (Recharge 5–6). The dragon exhales acid in a 30­-foot line that is 5 feet wide. Each creature in that line must make a DC 14 Dexterity saving throw, taking **49 (11d8)** acid damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one.*
> Challenge 7 (2,900 XP)

Stats from the SRD/DDB.

It is not uncommon to lose multiple members of your party if the DM plays the black dragon as intelligent and tactically competent.

This combat requires luck on your side and strategy. One last thing I will add, which is the only personal view on this, is that why not face your group with a lesser foe?

It can be equally fun while you don't lose respect to higher beings of this game which is the salt and pepper.  Otherwise it kind of feels like playing a video game with tons of cheats enabled.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I improved your post somewhat. How many battles have you had as a DM or player with a Young Black Dragon in the battle?

Comment: You bring up some interesting points, but they are not well supported.  Your first 3 paragraphs -- are they just your opinion, or is it based on something.  How does that address the questions asked?

Comment: Also, welcome to the stack Umut!  Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) when you have a moment, and feel free to peruse the [help](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) center for more in-depth info about the site.